# How would you translate/What would you translate

Tags: meaning

> How would you translate it into English?
>
> What would you translate it into English?

Are they both correct? What's the difference?

Comment: No. 

Answer (score 2):

No. The first one is correct, the second one is incorrect.

Loosely speaking, the word "how" asks for a way something goes or would go about doing something, whereas the word "what" asks for a way to go about understanding something.

For instance, if you were to ask "What does it do?", you would be trying to understand the function of whatever "it" is. The answer you would be expecting might be conclusive, e.g. "It does x.", or it might be inconclusive, e.g. "Look and see." Contrarily, if you were to ask "How does it do it?", you would already know what it did, and would be trying to understand the method it used to achieve its function.

The second one could be "What would you translate into English?", but it could not be "What would you translate it into English?", as you wrote it.

Comment: I am not clear on whether 1 is correct?

Comment: @user1425 1 is correct, 2 is incorrect.

Comment: There is the rub. You don't ask "How is your name?" but "What is your name?"

Comment: "How (in what way) would you translate _lundi_ into English?" - as distinct from "What is the English word for _lundi_?"